# android ListView set certain number of rows in layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to set my listView shows 10 rows in my screen which fits all kinds of screen size.
I'm NOT looking for getCount(){return 10;} or any other way to JUST show the first 10 items.(which I've seen a lot of people asked)
I want my listView to contain ALL the items, in other words, I want it:
a. more than 10(lets say 20) items adapted to the listView.
b. scrollable. 
c. listView shows only 10 rows in the screen. 
d. i hope to do it within xml
e. my listView height is unchangeable.( so the row height has to automatically adjust)

I don't know if they can all be done.
Appreciate for helping in advance.

Comment: Well you can get screen height divided by 10 , the result will be you're item height.

Comment: "the tricky part is I"? what do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't finished last time.
the trick part is that my listView is now full screen

Comment: did you mean "not* full screen", In that case you can take the height of the container of you're listView